# How to get all users (name, id) from a SharePoint group including AD groups with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, 2016, active-directory, jsom, groups

Is it possible to retrieve a list of all members of a sharepoint group, including members of included Sharepoint/AD groups using JavaScript?
As far as I know it is not possible using client side object model. Is there maybe REST call or a webService I can use?

Server side code is not an option, unfortunately.
Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

You can't enumerate users in AD groups natively with SharePoint APIs. SharePoint doesn't know who is inside groups in Active Directory.

The only way to do this is to expose custom code on your AD domain controller, and consume that from SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article, may be this article will give you idea.

[Get All users from SharePoint group including Active Directory](http://sharepointwiki.blogspot.com/2019/03/get-all-users-from-sharepoint-group.html).